# use distinct within case statement

Tags: sql, left-join, case, distinct

I have a query that uses multiple left joins and trying to get a SUM of values from one of the joined columns.

```
SELECT
SUM( case when session.usersessionrun =1 then 1 else 0 end) new_unique_session_user_count
FROM session
LEFT JOIN appuser ON appuser.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
            AND appuser.userid = session.userid
LEFT JOIN userdevice ON userdevice.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
            AND userdevice.userid = appuser.userid
WHERE session.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
 AND (session.uploadedon BETWEEN '2022-04-18 08:31:26' AND '2022-05-18 08:31:26')
```

But this obviously gives a redundant `session.usersessionrun=1` counts since it's a joined resultset.

Here the logic was to mark the user as `new` if the sessionrun for that record is `1`.

I grouped by `userid` and `usersessionrun` and it shows that the records are repeated.

```
userid. sessionrun. count
628212  1           2
627a01  1           4
```

So what I was trying to do was something like

```
SUM(CASE distinct(session.userid) AND WHEN session.usersessionrun = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new_unique_session_user_count
```

i.e. for every unique user count, session.usersessionrun = 1 should only be done once.

Comment: If `usersessionrun` is not equal to 1 for any user, that should not be included in the count?

Comment: If that's the case, you can try something like this. `COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN session.usersessionrun = 1 THEN session.userid  END) new_unique_session_user_count`

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the fact that it's valid for all makes and versions of database server software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, JOIN operations can generate combinatorial explosions of data.

You need a subquery to count your sessions by userid. Then you can treat the subquery as a virtual table and JOIN it to the other tables to get the information you need in your result set.

The subquery (nothing in my answer is debugged):

```sql
            SELECT COUNT(*) new_unique_session_user_count, 
                   session.userid
              FROM session
             WHERE session.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
               AND session.uploadedon BETWEEN '2022-04-18 08:31:26'
                                          AND '2022-05-18 08:31:26'
               AND session.usersessionrun = 1
               AND session.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
             GROUP BY userid
```

This subquery summarizes your session table and has one row per userid. The trick to avoiding JOIN-created combinatorial explosions is using subqueries that generate results with only one row per data item mentioned in a JOIN's ON-clause.

Then, you join it with the other tables like this

```sql
SELECT summary.new_unique_session_user_count
  FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) new_unique_session_user_count, 
                   session.userid
              FROM session
             WHERE session.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
               AND session.uploadedon BETWEEN '2022-04-18 08:31:26'
                                          AND '2022-05-18 08:31:26'
               AND session.usersessionrun = 1
               AND session.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
             GROUP BY userid
       ) summary
  JOIN appuser ON appuser.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
            AND appuser.userid = summary.userid
  JOIN userdevice ON userdevice.appid = '6279df3bd2d3352aed591583'
            AND userdevice.userid = appuser.userid
```

There may be better ways to structure this query, but it's hard to guess at them without more information about your table definitions and business rules.